# Buchberger's criterion to show Grobner basis for linear forms

Tags: commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $k$ be a field. A polynomial of the form $l=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$ is called a linear form ($a_i\in k$), and its support is the set of all variables $x_i$ such that $a_i\neq 0$.

Let $L\subseteq k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be an ideal generated by some linear forms. Let $S$ be the set of all linear forms in $L$ whose support is minimal (i.e., there doesn't exist another nonzero linear form with the support being a strict subset of this set.)

I can show that $S$ is finite, and I want to show that $S$ is a Grobner basis of $L$ by using Buchberger's criterion. So, suppose $A=x_k+\cdots,B=x_l+\cdots$ are two elements of $S$ (where the leading coefficient is scaled to be $1$. If $k\neq l$, I want to show that $x_lA-x_kB$ leaves zero remainder when dividing by elements of $S$. How to show that?

Comment: Note that A and B are elements of $S$, and they have different leading coefficients. Let's assume that $l<k$. So, first reduce with $A$ as long as possible. Can you then prove that the remainder is divisible by $B$?

Comment: @JohannesKloos Yes, that's true because $x_lA-x_kB=A(x_l-B)-B(x_k-A)$. Now, what happens in the case where the leading monomials are the same (i.e. $k=l$)? Here we cannot reduce by $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Didn't you want to show this for $k \neq l$? Anyway, if $k = l$, you have found a critical pair. Since $L$ is an ideal, certainly $D := x_l A -x_k B \in L$. By definition of $S$, there's some $g \in S$ whose support is strictly contained in that of $D$. What can you deduce from this?

Comment: @JohannesKloos Right, I just realized that the case $k=l$ is not as easy as I thought. If $k=l$, do you want to define $D$ to be $A-B$, instead of $x_lA-x_kB$? If so, sure there is some $g\in S$ whose support is contained in that of $D$ (but I don't see why "strictly contained"). And I also don't see what would follow.

Comment: Right, scratch the "strictly". If its support is contained, you can reduce by $g$, yielding $E$ (and if you do it right, you can reduce in such a way the the leading coefficient of $D$ is reduced to zero), thereby getting a polynomial that is smaller according to the monomial ordering. By properties of the reduction, $E \in L$ again, so you can repeat the process. Because of well-foundedness, this can only happen finitely many times. What would the normal form look like, when it's in $L$?

Comment: @JohannesKloos I see. Because the reduction can only happen finitely many times, we must eventually reach $0$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea here.